# Painfully slow function calling

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio

I stumbled on something interesting while working in Visual Studio with C++.  I was calling a function I made to set pixels to the screen through a nested for loop, for X and Y screen coordinates.  I discovered that if I did the operations in my main() function my program would run at 250 frames per second, yet if I moved it to an outside function and called it the frame rate dropped to 30 frames per second.

I did some investigating with a test program, and it replicated what happened in my program.  Below is an illustration of what I did....

If I run the following program....

```
void main()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) // Loop a billion times
   {
         1+1; // do something
   }
}
```

It runs in 1.6 seconds.

However, if I run the following code, which does exactly the same thing except by calling an outside function....

```
void onePlusOne()
{
    1+1;
}

void main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) // Loop a billion times
   {
         onePlusOne(); // call function instead
   }
}
```

It takes 18 second to execute.

Now, I CAN actually avoid calling the function and just have the code I need in my main(), but it makes it very messy and unreadable.

Please tell I'm doing something wrong or I've got my Visual Studio settings set wrong or something.

Comment: If I compile both programs with `/O2`, they execute both in less than one second (didn't do exact measuring). You'll have to tell us the settings with which you invoke your compiler, and the exact compiler version. And you should know that `void main` is not legal C++. It must be `int main`. Also note that keeping stuff separate and manageable is nothing OOP invented. It's the principle of *any* kind of structured programming! OOP in a nutshell is "virtual functions". Without virtual functions, you don't use OOP.

Comment: Without looking at the actual onePlusOne it's difficult to guess what could have been optimized int the first version.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'm looking into it now.  I'd appreciate anyone's help.  I'm using Visual Studio 2013, version 12.0.3.1101.00

Comment: Your benchmark is utterly meaningless. Entire blog posts and books are written on the subject.

Comment: You should not edit your question if you find the solution. You should rather post an answer yourself. Remember, SO is a Q&A site, and the content you post here should be in line with this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was running so slow calling the function is because I had it in debug mode.  In Release mode it's the same.  Now that raises more questions for me, like why does that happen, but anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: To elaborate on @Puppy 's "meaningless": It's hard to build meaningful benchmarks with optimizing compilers. You had debug mode on (=non-optimizing) which meant that the "meaningless" function call was actually executed. Function calls are expensive because registers need to be saved, stack pointers incremented etc. That may well take 10 times as long as the few instructions *within*  the function. An optimizing compiler would inline those few lines. And if  `onePlusOne()` actually contains only the expression `1+1` with no observable effects it will be optimized away completely.